# Обработка нажатий одновременно нескольких клавиш

Tags: java, swing

Хочу чтобы оба игрока могли играть одновременно, а не по очереди. По возможности - проще

```
public class OneClass implements KeyListener, ActionListener{

JFrame frame;
JButton button1,button2,button_cel;
String s="";

OneClass(){
//Стандарт, можно не читать

    frame=new JFrame();
    frame.setFocusable(true);
    frame.addKeyListener(this);
    button1=new JButton();
    button2=new JButton();
    button1.addActionListener(this);
    button2.addActionListener(this);
    button_cel=new JButton();
    button_cel.setSize(20, 20);
    button1.setFocusable(false);
    button2.setFocusable(false);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.add(button1);
    frame.add(button2);
    button1.setBackground(Color.RED);
    button2.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    frame.setLocation(0,0);
    frame.setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height-35);
    button1.setSize(10,10);
    button2.setSize(10, 10);
    button1.setLocation(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width/2, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height/2-5);
    button2.setLocation(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width/2-10, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height/2-5);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(240,240,240));

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            new OneClass();
        }
    });

}

//Вот тут-самое интерестное
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    button1.setSize(10, 10);
    button1.setText("");
    if(e.getKeyCode()==87){button2.setLocation(button2.getLocation().x, button2.getLocation().y-10);}
    if(e.getKeyCode()==68){button2.setLocation(button2.getLocation().x+10, button2.getLocation().y);}
    if(e.getKeyCode()==83){button2.setLocation(button2.getLocation().x, button2.getLocation().y+10);}
    if(e.getKeyCode()==65){button2.setLocation(button2.getLocation().x-10, button2.getLocation().y);}
    if(e.getKeyCode()==38){button1.setLocation(button1.getLocation().x, button1.getLocation().y-10);}
    if(e.getKeyCode()==39){button1.setLocation(button1.getLocation().x+10, button1.getLocation().y);}
    if(e.getKeyCode()==40){button1.setLocation(button1.getLocation().x, button1.getLocation().y+10);}
    if(e.getKeyCode()==37){button1.setLocation(button1.getLocation().x-10, button1.getLocation().y);}

}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println(e.getKeyCode());

}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
}

}

}
```

[Вот](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/85632165/Just_cubs.jar) jar

Импорты пропустил

Comment: @iamqwerty, Вы почитайте сначала [вот это](http://hashcode.ru/questions/191109/%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B5-%D1%85%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2).

А потом подумайте, что именно Вы спрашиваете. Неужели всерьез считаете, что все кинутся изучать эту программу?

Comment: Добавил jar для лучшего "восприятия"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как я понял, поблема в том, что когда кто-то зажимает кнопку, то если в это время кто-то жмёт свою, то первый перестаёт двигаться?

Дело вот в чём. Ваш код полагается на тот факт, что система генерирует повторно события если кнопка зажата. Но есть одна особенность. Дело в том, что если при зажатой кнопке нажать другую, то генерирование повторных событий для первой зажатой кнопки прекращается.

Чтобы обойти это вам надо действовать иначе. Напимер, вы можете отслеживать какие кнопки были нажаты, а какие отпущены. А потом по таймеру выполнять действия.

Вот, я набросал в vi простой пример чтобы пояснить идею, так что пардон за форматирование. И имейте в виду, что это просто пример. В жизни так делать не надо..

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    private Point first = new Point(0,0);
    private Point second = new Point(1, 0);
    private Set<String> pressed = new HashSet<>();

    public Main() {
    setSize(800, 600);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            }

            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                pressed.remove(Character.toString(e.getKeyChar()));
            }

            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            pressed.add(Character.toString(e.getKeyChar()));
            }

        });

        Timer t = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                setTitle(pressed.toString());

            boolean repaint = false;

            if (pressed.contains("a")) {
                first = add(first, -1, 0);
                repaint = true;
            }
            if (pressed.contains("d")) {
                first = add(first, 1, 0);
                repaint = true;
            }
            if (pressed.contains("w")) {
                first = add(first, 0, -1);
                repaint = true;
            }
            if (pressed.contains("s")) {
                first = add(first, 0, 1);
                repaint = true;
            }
            if (pressed.contains("j")) {
                second = add(second, -1, 0);
                repaint = true;
            }
            if (pressed.contains("l")) {
                second= add(second, 1, 0);
                repaint = true;
            }
            if (pressed.contains("i")) {
                second = add(second, 0, -1);
                repaint = true;
            }
            if (pressed.contains("k")) {
                second = add(second, 0, 1);
                repaint = true;
            }

            if (repaint) {
                invalidate();
                repaint();
                }
                }
        });
        t.start();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

    g2d.translate(50, 50);
    g2d.scale(16, 16);

    g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2d.fillRect((int)first.getX(), (int)first.getY(), 1, 1);

    g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g2d.fillRect((int)second.getX(), (int)second.getY(), 1, 1);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main().setVisible(true);
    }

    private static Point add(Point p, int dx, int dy) {
    return new Point((int)p.getX() + dx, (int)p.getY() + dy);
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Понял, правда, не все, но дочитаю Шилдта и пойму :-)

Comment: Шилдт вам в этом деле вряд ли поможет... ну да беды от его чтения не будет.